# Identify Crawlers From User Agent

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to track all visitors(Os,Browser and more details) to my site.For that i am saving the useragent and URLs and other essential data into database.Later Upon execution of Crone,the user agent is analyzed and fetch browser,Os. But I want to identify crawlers(as they cannot be considerd as visitors). So is there any way to identify crawlers from user agent.
Did user Agents of Crawlers follow any common Patterns?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is for programming Q&A.  Questions generally include broken source code, which yours does not.  You probably intended to ask this question on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify them by **User-Agent** or **IP** (subnet).

The first method isn't reliable, because anyone can identify as any Crawler just modifying the User-Agent.
The second method is obviously better.

These are two of the many lists on the web: http://www.user-agents.org/ (See the legend: R = Robot, crawler, spider) - http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html

Another one: http://www.karavadra.net/blog/2010/list-of-crawlers-bots-and-their-ip-addresses/

Answer (score 1):

Using `User-Agent` strings for anything important is unreliable and a bad idea.

Any malicious crawlers will probably send the UA string of a popular browser. Proper search engine crawlers will always send a recognisable UA string, but theres nothing to stop me configuring my web browser to pretend to be one of those crawlers.

If you must do this, see [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) and the `crawler` element of the value if returns.

Answer (score 1):

The [Web Robots Page](http://www.robotstxt.org/) includes a [list of known crawlers/robots](http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html) that includes user agent patterns that may be used to identify known bots that are well behaved (and listed in the database).

But as DaveR said, it is difficult to stop someone who ignores the rules, and not every crawler is in the robotstxt.org database.